# WPF TargetNullValue for Dictonary Binding not working

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a dictonary (of String, String) that may not have an entry for a specific key.

In XAML I want to cover that case by the following line:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyDictonary[myKey], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource uriToImageConverter}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource myStaticImage} }"/>
```

The code works fine if I don't bind to a dictonary but have a String in my viewmodel which is `Nothing`.

I also checked if it is the converters vault but the converter is never called if there is no valid string.

Thanks in advance for help/explanaitions of what I am missing here.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you might also find the [FallbackValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue) setting useful, which will be used if the binding fails for whatever reason.

Comment: @ShahinDohan if you make that an answer and reference Yanting's explanation, I would make this the accepted answer. thank you!

Comment: YantingChen has the right answer, the reason TargetNullValue doesn't work for you is because the your `Binding MyDictonary[myKey]` is failing due to a KeyNotFoundException, which is also why FallbackValue does work :)

Comment: Search for "System.Windows.Data Error" in the "Output window" of Visual Studio. It will help you find binding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dictionary entry for "myKey" with Nothing (MyDictonary.Add("myKey", Nothing)) so that it can get the "Nothing" value without causing an exception.

Another way to achieve this is to add an additional "DictionaryValue" property on ViewModel.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DictionaryKey, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding DictionaryValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource uriToImageConverter}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource myStaticImage} }"/>
</StackPanel>


Public Class ViewModel
    Inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        MyDictonary = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    End Sub

    Private _key As String

    Public Property DictionaryKey As String
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)

            If _key <> value Then
                _key = value
                RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(DictionaryKey))
                RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(DictionaryValue))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property DictionaryValue As String
        Get

            If DictionaryKey IsNot Nothing AndAlso MyDictonary.Keys.Contains(DictionaryKey) Then
                Return MyDictonary(DictionaryKey)
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property MyDictonary As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```